# Loading data using SELECT as a post value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following HTML:

```
<select name="compet" id="compet"></select>
<select  name="spage" id="spage">
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="insert">Insert</option>
  <option value="ranking">change</option>
  <option value="details">Details</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="ChangePage" id="Goto" onclick="change_page()" value="ChangePage" />
```

and the following jQuery (I want the click on the button to load a new page via AJAX into a div):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  function change_page(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '', // This is where I want to get the value based on the SELECT
      type: 'POST',
      data: { compet: $('#compet').val() },
      success: function(data){
        $(".myresult").html(data);
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

I want the URL to be based on which item in the `SELECT` is chosen. Not sure how to accomplish this, though. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: where is your ".myresult" element? at what url does "this slecets menu" reside? I'm afraid you have completely missed programming basics...

Comment: I took the liberty of cleaning up the wide variety of flagrant typos, poorly formed HTML tags and so on... that should be a good start...

Comment: myresutl is div class name contain database table and the compet post used in sql query for this table

Comment: I have index.php page include select menu
at the index I have div with "class=myresul"
so I have many pages at site like insert.php, ranking.php
I want when i select names from select menu "spages" .. open this page in myresult elemnt

Comment: Please don't change the question in the comments -- edit the original question

Comment: ok but
I just answered user1660584 question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (nb, not tested)

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  function change_page(){

     var myurl;

     switch($("#spage").val())
     {
        case "home":
          myurl = "http://mysite.com";
          break;
        case "insert":
          myurl = "http://mysite.com/insert";
          break;
        case "ranking":
          myurl = "http://mysite.com/ranking";
          break;
 // etc
     }


    $.ajax({
      url: myurl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: { compet: $('#compet').val() },
      success: function(data){
        $(".myresult").html(data);
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: nothing happened
no respons
I changed somthings but nothing happened
I changed myurl in each case to " home.php","insert.php" etc
I changed case "home" to case 0 and case "insert" to case 1 etc.
but nothing changed
thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

it is worked now after I change in this HTML

```
<select name="compet" id="compet"></select>
<select  name="spage" id="spage">
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="insert">Insert</option>
  <option value="ranking">change</option>
  <option value="details">Details</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="ChangePage" id="Goto" onclick="change_page()" value="ChangePage" /> // I changed type to button from submit
```

Thank you